Question in Topology Without Tears by Sidney A. Morris.
I currently reading Topology Without Tears by Sidney A. Morris and I already read through eight chapters which topic is Finite Product. I try to show that "open interval (a,b) in $\mathbb{R}$ is $F_\sigma$-set" where $F_\sigma$-set mean it is union of a countable number of closed sets.
My thought is use singelton $\{x\}$ where $x\in(a,b)$ to complete the proof since its complement $(-\infty,x)\cup (x,\infty)$ is open set in $\mathbb{R}$. But I also know that every open interval in $\mathbb{R}$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable set which makes $(a,b)$ an uncountable set also. That implies there are uncountably infinite numbers of element between $(a,b)$ so the union $\bigcup_{x\in(a,b)}\{x\}$ is also uncountable set.
Anything inappropriate in my thought or any hints for this question? Thanks for the response!

Your thought about $(a,b)=\cup{x}$ is correct: it's an uncountable union, which means that representation does not show that $(a,b)$ is $F_\sigma$.

One idea is to approximate this interval from inside with closed sets. Take $A_n=[a+\frac{1}{n},b-\frac{1}{n}]$. Then:
$$(a,b)=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} A_n$$
It is clear that the RHS is contained in LHS, as $A_n\subset (a,b)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. On the other hand. let $x\in (a,b)$. Since $a+\frac{1}{n}\to a$ and $b-\frac{1}{n}\to b$, there exists some $n$ such that $a<a+\frac{1}{n}<x<b-\frac{1}{n}<b$, that is $x\in A_n$.

Thanks! But what is this sentence $a+\frac{1}{n}\to a$ mean?

It's a shortcut for $\lim_{n \to \infty} (a+1/n) \to a$.
